# How to add composite view like HashMap to twirl in playframework 2.4.x

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.4, twirl

I want to add a HashMap Object contains many different object(s) to the twirl template, because I do not like adding one by one as parameter to the twirl, it breaks the rule with design patterns.

the normal style:

```
views.html.index.render(object1, object2, list3, list4, ...);

@(object1:Object1Model, object2:Object2Model, list3: List[Object3Model], list4: List[Object4Model])
```

Is there any solution to set and get parameters like this?

```
Map data = new HashMap();
data.put("object1", object1);
data.put("object2", object2);
data.put("list3", list3);
data.put("list4", list4);
views.html.index.render(data);
```

How to get and define the objects in HashMap in twirl, the official twirl document is too simple...

```
@(data:Map) 
Object1Model object1 = (Object1Model) data.get("object1");
Object2Model object2 = (Object2Model) data.get("object2");
List list3 = (List) data.get("list3");
List list4 = (List) data.get("list4");
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For type-safety you can create a dedicated class with fields of required types, the additional benefit is that sophisticated IDEs will recognize types of the fields and/or autocomplete field names, so it help you to prevent mistakes in the views.

Of course as in each class you can also use the benefits of constructor and/or getters/setters.

(*pseudo code*):

```
package viewhelpers;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SomeViewHelper {

    public String header;
    public List<String> labels = new ArrayList<>();
    public List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

Fill it in controller somehow:

```
public static Result incomes() {
    SomeViewHelper data = new SomeViewHelper();
    data.header = "Incomes in first quarter";
    data.labels = Arrays.asList("Jan", "Feb", "Mar");
    data.values = Arrays.asList(121, 122, 123);
    return ok(views.html.incomes.render(data));
}
```

and use in the view like:

```
@(data: viewhelpers.SomeViewHelper)

<h1>@data.header</h1>
<table>
    <tr>
        @for(label <- data.labels) {
            <th>@label</th>
        }
    </tr>
    <tr>
        @for(value <- data.values) {
            <td>@value</td>
        }
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks, i will try. but if i want to add more dynamic objects, not just simple string and list,  this also will not be so easy.